# ajax database request not returning German characters?

Tags: php, ajax, database, char, set

My table which I am getting my data from is in "Latin_1" however when the data is returned the fields with German characters in get returned as empty. 
Why is it doing this ? 
does json encode affect the char set? 
other than that I am completely lost.

I have read you can set the character set in php but it is already set correctly and the table has the special characters in ?

Edit//

here is the code i am using 
__php:

```
function getInfo($country){

    $rows = array();
    $query = "SELECT name,add1,add2,town,district,postcode FROM stockistsWorld WHERE country = '". mysql_escape_string($country) ."' LIMIT 4 ";
    //$query = "SELECT Name,add1 FROM stockistsUK LIMIT 10";
    $result = mysqli_query($this->conn, $query);
    /* numeric array */

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM)){

         $rows[] = $row;

        }

    return $rows;
}
```

and this is the ajax request_*_*

```
function ajaxData(country){
//get data from database return into inf array 
var infArray = new Array();
 $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'php/Maps.php',
        data: {country: country},
        success: function(data){
        infArray = JSON.parse(data);
        geoCodeClientSide(infArray);
        }           
    });
```

}

Comment: Why are you using `mysql_escape_string` when you are working with `mysql**i**`

Comment: This is my first time, i just thought that you had to do that to stop sql injection

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: Thankyou peehaa, but do you have any idea on the encoding ? I can't find out anything more on it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: I have set every possible encoding in the database, html, tables, mysqli connection to utf-8 but it still is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please set the charset for your db/table as utf-8.

Thanks,
Neo

Comment: I have changed it to this but it still is not returning the umlauts ? i thought utf 8 didn't support this?

Comment: please check the specific data in table manually, are you able to read those characters? If not then you need to insert the data again after changing the charset to utf-8

Comment: in my sql if i query the database the special characters turn up

Comment: Okay, can you print the 'data' before coverting it to JSON and check if its coming fine?

Comment: I think your html/php is unable to render chrset as utf-8.

Comment: so i took it back to just echoing straight from the database call umlauts come as � however when not converting to json the rest of the field is returned #sobloodyconfused

Comment: so i tested it with a new table and it worked so by that logic it must be a problem with the table